# rgba does not make the background color transparent

Tags: html, css

The problem is `rgba` transparency.
I am supposed to change its background and make it transparent.
However, it only changes the background color, but does not make it transparent.

I often run into this problem, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

I tried to figure out why it does not work sometimes even the way I code is exactly same as other time when it works.

And I saw a couple of suggestions like spacing between `rgba` and `()`, the range of alpha and so on. But none of them was quite helpful.

Then I came across the advice below. (cannot remember the source)
"rgba does not affect child elements". I barely remember, so I might be wrong and since English is not my first language, I was not able to understand well.

I have the following questions

1.> If the statement is correct, would you like please explain what that means?

2.> The code attached is the example of this problem. The background has been changed but is not transparent. So, please let me know whether the problem is with child and parents elements.

3.> Let me know anything you notice when you read my code below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  background: url("./img/vbs/vbs4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.outer {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 50, .5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  background: white;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.inner>h1 {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include relevant HTML

Comment: well i edit your code to a snippet and if you will add body {background: black;} you will see that the transparency does work...

Comment: If the inner div covers the outer div completely, and the inner div isn't transparent, you won't see any transparency.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code above, the element `.outer` is the only one with styled with `rgba()`, so that element/s only have a alpha/opacity/transparency applied to it. And the `.outer` is a parent of `.inner`, you have put the child with no transparency applied to it with an element with a transparency style applied to it.
You also mentioned that someone said that spacing between might be the problem but no, even you put a long 2 spaces or no spaces between it, it will not affect the css code.
The phrase "rgba does not affect child elements" you mentioned was correct, like I said the only element with a `rgba` is the `.outer`. It like painting into a glass then you put a objects to the glass, but the object is not a glass. So the glass only have a behavior/characteristics of being transparent.

This is fix code you attached, just added an `opacity` to the the `.inner` element

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  background: url("./img/vbs/vbs4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.outer {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 50, .5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  background: white;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 20%;
  /* opacity applied to the child outer (inner) */
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.inner>h1 {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but a question again. since opacity is used, the heading tag inside inner div tag is transparent now. I cannot fix this problem then?

Comment: @vincent you can set the background using `rgba` of the heading tag, that way you can set if you want it to be transparent. BTW, you might also want to indicate the dimension of each element.

Answer (score 0):

you should also set the internal elements to be transparent.